# LaTex Multicolumn Bar Too long, bug?

Tags: tables

I am encountering problems with a seperation bar using LaTex package **\multirow**.
As can be seen in the picture, the red circled bar is just too much and messing up the layout of my table.
Does someone have an idea how to fix? I tried to fix it by putting/deleting "|" from/to everywhere. Also, making column 1 a multicolumn itself didn't make it. I'd appreciate help a lot.

My code is the following:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption[..]{...}
    \label{...}

    \begin{tabular}{c | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf{STATION}}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bf{OCEAN BOTTOM}} \\ \hline
    & \bf{Latitude / Longitude} & \bf{Depth [m]}    \\ \hline

    RUM41  &  27$^\circ$ 43.98' S / 65$^\circ$ 20.04' E  &  5461  \\ 
    .
    .
    .

    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: please edit your code in the question to be a _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: unrelated but note that `\bf` which is deprecated in latex2e, does not take an argument the syntax is  `\bf Depth [m]` not ` \bf{Depth [m]}` (the `{}` in that context just form an unused group not an argument delimiter)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I'll take it into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You have a spurious `\\` creating a blank line with just one cell (ending in the vertical rule(. Delete the `\\` here

```
   \begin{tabular}
  {c | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}} 
    \\
```